# How to open another Account's User folder using Terminal?

Tags: terminal, bash, user-account, sudo

I used to be able to use one of these commands to switch to another user account (my own) to work on it.

```
john$ login admin
password:

admin$ open .
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -610 for the file /Users/admin/.
```

I have tried other methods as well.

```
john$ su - admin
john$ exec su - admin
john$ sudo -u admin bash
```

They all result in the same error. I understand it's a security restriction. The question is what rules are restricting this? I do have the password shouldn't I be allowed, once signing in, access to those files?

What can I do to gain access as if I am in that user account?

---

EDIT

Also tried:

```
john$ ssh admin@localhost
Password:
admin$ open .
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -610 for the file /Users/admin.
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been a restriction for a very long time - I have 10 yr old machines out in the field where in order to launch things as the GUI user we su to be that user and then run the gui app we need.  In summary you are able to do anything that doesn't require the UI once you've done a su/ssh/login as the other user.  However once you want to do something with the UI you are out of luck because the things running in the UI need to be run as the same user who is logged in with the UI showing.

Comment: Are you able to achieve what you need by just logging in as the other user (i.e. swap to that user using the quick login menu in the top right)? OR run as the other user and VNC to the machine when needed)  Actually apple vnc lets you connect and swap to a different user (but obviously needs to be from another machine).

Comment: Of course you could change file permissions - e.g. be in the group for the other user and change file permissions to g+r.

Comment: I think this all changed recently, within the last two major releases. It may have been a security hole that was finally fixed? I really got used to that "security hole". I can log in as the other user and do everything as normal.

Comment: There is also a new security permission (look in Security & Privacy -> Privacy "Files & Folders"  and "Full Disk Permission") that you may need to grant to the apps you want to use.  That came in catalina.

Comment: What is the best way to change those permissions so I don't change permissions on files/folders further down in the directory structure?

Comment: You have to change it everywhere you need it - and to all the files too.  Although the "special" parts of a user directory are still inaccessible until you grant "Files & Folders" [at least that's my experience - even as root I couldn't see them from the terminal]

Comment: I think I am better off finally combining these two user accounts than messing around with permissions. That seems to have always caused severe issues on binaries I have installed - thinking of homebrew package manager.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122663/discussion-between-john-and-mr-r).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the login command, you're switching accounts. You cannot then open the file in your current Finder/account if your current account doesn't have access.

The analogous operation to doing `login` when interacting with Finder would be to fully switch over to that account. All running GUI programs are going to be using your current account.

If you frequently need to access these files, you could keep them in `/Users/Shared` or you can change the permissions on them (if you select the folder the files are in you can make that folder accessible to both accounts and recursively apply it to contents).

Comment: I second Ezekiels opinion. Storing files in /Users/Shared is the most efficient means of doing this. That is also assuming you’re the only administrative account (on the machine) and the data is not sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

[Jump Desktop](https://jumpdesktop.com/) will allow you to log in to the same computer you are using as a different user. You will have access to all of your files and apps.

I have not done this extensively, but I did test it and it worked in Jump Desktop.

The default macOS **Screen Sharing.app** will not do this.

[Screens 4](https://www.edovia.com/en/screens-mac/) *seemed* like it was going to work, but it did not successfully connect.